# how to use google storage as img libary?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-storage

I want to build a portfolio website for photography.

For performance I want to store the photos in google cloud and get them with API or URL.

I can't find any tutorials, how to build this.

It don't have to be google cloud.

If you could give me keywords or a instruction, it would be great.

Answer (score 2):

You should check out google cloud storage https://cloud.google.com/storage. It is similar to aws (amazon web services) s3 storage service.

You can find the full documentation here https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/introduction#quickstarts.

I hope that helps.